# Adding marker on map by receiving latitude and longitude another acivity

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

I have a fragment in the main activity which contains map.By default i have added a marker at Bhopal city in India. I have a Navigation Drawer, Which has an options set location. Now, when I enter the the name of the city I want my marker to move to that  Location. I used Intent for this, but that didn't work. My code for fragment is

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
GoogleMap mgoogleMap;
MapView mapView;
View view;
Double Lat,Longg;
int c = 0;
public MyFragment(){


}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater , ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
  /*  Lat = Double.parseDouble(getArguments().getString("Lattitude"));
    Longg = Double.parseDouble(getArguments().getString("Longitude"));
    if(Lat!=null)
        c++;*/
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main,container , false);
    return view;

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mapView = view.findViewById(R.id.map);
    if(mapView!=null)
    mapView.onCreate(null);
    mapView.onResume();
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
    mgoogleMap = googleMap;
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    if (c == 0) {
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(23.2599, 77.4126)).title("BHOPAL"));
        CameraPosition bhopal = CameraPosition.builder().target(new LatLng(23.2599, 77.4126)).zoom(16).bearing(0).build();
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(bhopal));
    } else {
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Lat, Longg)));
        CameraPosition city = CameraPosition.builder().target(new LatLng(Lat, Longg)).zoom(16).bearing(0).build();
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(city));
    }
}
```

}

And my Location activity is:

```
public class LocationActivtiy extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText place;
private EditText lat,longi;
private double latt,longg;
private Button done;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_activtiy);
    place = findViewById(R.id.loc);
    lat = findViewById(R.id.lat);
    longi = findViewById(R.id.longi);
    done = findViewById(R.id.done);
    List<Address>addresses = null;
    if(Geocoder.isPresent()){
        try {
            if(place.getText()!=null) {
                String location = place.getText().toString();
                Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
                addresses = gc.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
                Address addr = addresses.get(0);
                latt = addr.getLatitude();
                longg = addr.getLongitude();
            }else if(lat.getText()!=null){
                latt = Double.parseDouble(lat.getText().toString());
                longg = Double.parseDouble(longi.getText().toString());
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Enter any one 
value",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
                }
     catch (IOException e) {
         Toast.makeText(this,"Services Not 
available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new 
Intent(LocationActivtiy.this,MyFragment.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putDouble("Lattitude",latt);
            bundle.putDouble("Longitude",longg);
            MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
            myFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

I have 2 options, Either I can move to that position by city name or by latitude or longitude. But these are coming from different activity. Also, If my app opens for the first time By default marker should be set on Bhopal location.

Comment: I got this. I cannot call fragment this way.